# People Counting Video Analytics: data acquisition parameters

Tags: datasets

I am interested in understanding how to choose data-acquisition parameters for the subject matter:

- Frame Resolution
- Frame rates (FPS)

The goal is to have 'enough' (preferably the minimal) resolution and frames to enable AI to identify people.

## QUESTIONS

1. Are there any published rules of thumb or processes to select video parameters?
2. Is there a term or label for the selection of video parameters for AI projects?